# Out-of-order results in the READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level?

Tags: isolation-level

On the Wikipedia page for [Isolation (database systems)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Dirty_reads), when explaining *dirty reads*, it says:

> The only thing that may be prevented in the READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level is updates appearing out of order in the results; that is, earlier updates will always appear in a result set before later updates.

I am confused about in which case updates would appear out of order in the results. I think it is impossible and not what READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level avoids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That entry is poorly-worded, so I don't blame you for getting confused by it.

The author(s) appear to be trying to make the point that even when *dirty reads* are allowed, it is impossible to encounter changes made by a later update before seeing changes made by an earlier update.

In other words, a 'dirty read' will always include all changes (committed or not) up that point in time.

It seems to be a way to stress a perceived difference compared with *non-repeatable reads*, as the preceding sentence mentions:

> Dirty reads work similarly to non-repeatable reads; however, the second transaction would not need to be committed for the first query to return a different result.

No such distinction appears in the original definitions as I understand them, so it would be better if the part you refer to were removed.

Note that an implementation of *read uncommitted isolation* is not required to experience dirty reads, just that it may. Several popular products provide a read uncommitted isolation level that delivers a much higher degree of isolation and protection from so-called read phenomena. This is explicitly allowed by the SQL Standard.